# Opaque Layer on top of semi-transparent layer

Tags: android, android-layout, alpha-transparency

I have an activity that is laid out as I want. When a user clicks a button, I am displaying a pop up edit text box. I want to put a middle layer between the pop up edittext and the primary layer that is semi-transparent to keep the user's focus on the popup.

So I set the alpha value on the middle layer to 0.5. However, the popup layer is now also rendering as semi-transparent, even if I explicitly set its alpha to 1.0.

```
<!-- this is the middle layer (I call it the 'curtain') -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/log_entry_reply_container_curtain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <!-- this is the popup layer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/log_entry_reply_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="1.0"
        style="@style/RoundedCornersView" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/log_entry_tv_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/enter_reply"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/log_entry_reply_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/log_entry_tv_reply"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="top"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make this middle layer semi-transparent while still keeping the top layer fully opaque? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi create semitransperent.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke android:width="2dp" />



    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#29000000"
        android:startColor="#29000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

Note.Stroke,gradient,corners as per your requirement you need to change.

Add the line below line in xml code:

```
   android:background="@drawable/semitransperent"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I marked this as the solution, because it works. However, for anyone who might use this, I would point out that the body of the `<shape>` doesn't need any of the `<stroke>`, `<gradient>`, or `<corners>` tags. All I needed to resolve the original question was simply `<solid android:color="#cc000000" />` where 'cc' represents whatever alpha value you want to apply to your background. Thanks for the suggestion. It definitely works!